# VBA: loop through various Excel files and copy a cokumn into a master file

Tags: vba, excel

I need VBA Code which opens all xlxs files in a folder and copies a specific column of each file and puts this data in a master sheet. All the data needs to be copied into the first column of the master sheet and new data should always added below.

For older Excel versions without power query I tried this but it does not work :-(

```
 Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String

Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

  myExtension = "*.xls*"

  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  Do While myFile <> ""

      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    lastRow = Workbooks("SUMMARY.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

      DoEvents


    wb.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(150, 6)).Copy_ Workbooks("SUMMARY.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(lastRow + 1, 1), Cells(lastRow + 150, 1))


       wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

         DoEvents


      myFile = Dir
  Loop


ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Hello I use Excel 2016

Comment: By the sounds of it PowerQuery could be the way to go - I'm still on an ancient version though, so don't know about such modern things.  Otherwise, please post your code and point out specifically where you're having problems.

Answer (score 2):

Excel 2016 has a new and fairly simple tool called PowerQuery built in that is perfect for this kind of thing, and much simpler than VBA. See Microsoft's site at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-files-in-a-folder-with-combine-binaries-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4 for an example, or google "Combine files" and "PowerQuery" and you'll see thousands of tutorials, videos, et cetera demonstrating how to do this in more detail.